# Why is this code not working, How do i fix it?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am not sure if anyone can help me here but I am having a problem in my for loop and my loop continuation.

This is what the code is supposed to output.

> ```
> Enter a starting integer value: 8
> Enter an ending integer value: 121
> Enter a positive increment: 17
> Sum (using a while loop): 413
> Sum (using a for loop): 413
> ```

This is what my code outputs.

> ```
> Enter the starting integer value: 8
> Enter the ending integer value: 121
> Enter the positive increment: 17
> Sum(using a while loop) = 413
> Sum(using a for loop)= 110
> ```

Here is my code if someone can help me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//defining the integers
int startingNumber, endingNumber, positiveIncrement;

cout <<"Enter the starting integer value: ";
cin >> startingNumber;
cout <<"Enter the ending integer value: ";
cin >> endingNumber;
cout <<"Enter the positive increment: ";
cin >> positiveIncrement;
//maiking sure the starting number is greater than 0
//also making sure the ending number is greater than
//the starting number.
if ((startingNumber <= 0) || (startingNumber > endingNumber))
{
  cout<<"Error in input provided"<< endl;
  return 0;
}
int while_loop_Sum = 0;
//start of while loop
while_loop_Sum = startingNumber;
while ((startingNumber + positiveIncrement) <= endingNumber)
{
  startingNumber += positiveIncrement;
  while_loop_Sum += startingNumber;
}
cout << "Sum(using a while loop) = " << while_loop_Sum << endl;
//end of while loop

//start of for loop
int for_loop_Sum = 0;
{
for ((for_loop_Sum = startingNumber);((startingNumber + 
positiveIncrement) <= endingNumber);(startingNumber += 
positiveIncrement))
{
  for_loop_Sum += (startingNumber+positiveIncrement);
}
cout << "Sum(using a for loop)= " << for_loop_Sum;
//end of for loop
}

return 0;
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your debugger say? Also, you had put the actual output, but what is your expected output?

Comment: Also, always check cin.fail(), like so: if( (cin >> myVarOfType).fail() ) { // handle error, could not convert to type }

Comment: @ChristopherPisz "This is what the code is supposed to output." ..expected output... "This is what my code outputs." ...actual output...

Comment: Its easier to read the code if you add the input hardcoded instead of reading it from `std::cin` (assuming the problem is not caused by reading the input from `std::cin`)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: the code outputs just fine, but it doesnt output what i need

Comment: @GarCB613 thats not a comment but an answer ;)

Comment: @ChristopherPisz -- you don't need to call `fail()` in a boolean context. `if (cin >> myVarOfType)` is sufficient; the stream object's conversion to `bool` tells you whether the attempted input failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never reset `starting_number` after the while loop! You `cin >> startingNumber;`, then in the while loop you `startingNumber += positiveIncrement;` and then you go on to use it in the for loop as if it's good, but it's not!

You need to store the **actual** starting number in a variable when you get it and then use some other temporary in the while and for to avoid this issue. Maybe something like:

```
cin >> startingNumber;
...
int tmpStarting = startingNumber;
while ((tmpStarting + positiveIncrement) <= endingNumber) {
    ...
}

...

tmpStarting = startingNumber; //Reset starting number for the for!
for(...
```